# How to control amp-live-list caching?

Tags: caching, amp-html

I'm implementing an `amp-live-list` for our site and I have everything set up. Everything looks good when I go the AMP version of my live blog pages (where the element is implemented) however when I run the URL through Google, i.e. `https://www.google.com/amp/www.example.com/test-live-blog/amp`, it can take up to 3-4 minutes for an update to come through even though polling is set to the minimum 15 seconds.

The delay directly on the AMP URL, i.e. `https://www.example.com/test-live-blog/amp`, is around the expected 15 second mark. Does Google AMP have a separate cache or request header it uses? What response header can I set to try and reduce this time to live for the AMP version of my document? I can't find any suitable documentation for these kinds of caching questions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: My code looks identical to the amp-live-list examples you can find [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-live-list/). I found there is a Google AMP Cache endpoint you can ping with a cache clear request along with the URL. Going to try and just hit that whenever a new post is added to the list but still looks like delay will be about 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The Google AMP Cache respect the max-age header, as specified in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview):

> The cache follows a "stale-while-revalidate" model. It uses the origin's caching headers, such as Max-Age, as hints in deciding whether a particular document or resource is stale. When a user makes a request for something that is stale, that request causes a new copy to be fetched, so that the next user gets fresh content.

The Google AMP cache, including the case where the cache ping is used, has some latency which is on the order of minutes and I have seen as low as a minute.